# Make Update with select statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update for some products their category in Database. But I get an error and I don’t understand where my statement is wrong. Please help. I want to find products that have in their name a specific word and after that I what to update the category for this products.

I want to select IDs from sho_posts where sho_posts.post_title contain this part of word '%Audio CD%' and after that to update the sho_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id with value 2 where sho_term_relationships.object_id=sho_posts.id

```
UPDATE sho_term_relationships 
   SET term_taxonomy_id = 2
 WHERE object_id = (SELECT `id` FROM `1876522_shoping`.`sho_posts` WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%Audio CD%')
```

Comment: - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

In your WHERE clause, to find the ids to update based on the subquery results, use `IN` instead of `=`

```
UPDATE sho_term_relationships 
   SET term_taxonomy_id = 2
   WHERE object_id IN (
      SELECT `id` FROM `1876522_shoping`.`sho_posts` 
      WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%Audio CD%')
```

You would use `=` only if you were certain the subquery would return a single row, it won't work if the subquery returns multiple rows. Using `IN` tests whether the object id is included in the subquery results.

Comment: now I get the error "Duplicate entry '3205-2' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: for this parameter for selection '%Audio CD%' I have 4 items

Comment: I want to find items that contains word "'%Audio CD%'" in sho_posts.post_title and get Ids after that I what update sho_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id whit value 2 where sho_posts.id=sho_term_relationships.object_id

Comment: @Tatar: if fixing this sql causes a duplicate entry error, is term_taxonomy_id the primary key? you can't update 2 rows to use the same primary key, that wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: @Tatar: my guess is that you're getting a constraint violation because you're doing something invalid that will cause two rows to have the same key information, but i'm only guessing. this is a separate error that you haven't given any information about.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use 'in' instead of '=' when updating multiple rows.

UPDATE sho_term_relationships 
   SET term_taxonomy_id = 2
 WHERE object_id **in** (SELECT `id` FROM `1876522_shoping`.`sho_posts` WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%Audio CD%')

Comment: I obtained this error "Duplicate entry '3205-2' for key 'PRIMARY'"